# Strong data typing bug

Tags: php, type-hinting

Is it normal to get the error "*Default value for parameters with a class type hint can only be NULL*" for a method in an interface defined as

```
public function nullify(bool $force=FALSE);
```

?

I need it to be bool, not an object, and FALSE by default.

Comment: It should work with php7

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no type hinting for boolean parameters in php (yet). You can only specify a class name or `array`.
Therefore `function foo(bool $b)` means: "the parameter $b must be an instance of the class 'bool' or null".

http://docs.php.net/language.oop5.typehinting:

> Functions are now able to force parameters to be objects (by specifying the name of the class in the function prototype) or arrays (since PHP 5.1).

Answer (score 5):

As already stated, type hinting only works for arrays and object.  Your function can be written like this:

```
public function nullify($force=FALSE){
  $force=(bool)$force;
  //further stuff
}
```

Comment: Or raise an user_error or throw an exception if false===is_bool($force) to get closer to the "catchable fatal error" php raises for unsuitable parameters.

Answer (score 3):

PHP 5 type hinting is limited to a specific class (or one of its subclasses), or an array. You cannot specify any other scalar types.

Answer (score 1):

You can't force a parameter to be a boolean.

As found in [language.oop5.typehinting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php) :

> PHP 5 introduces type hinting. Functions are now able to force parameters to be objects [...], interfaces, arrays (since PHP 5.1) or callable (since PHP 5.4).

[...]

Type hints **can not be used with scalar types** such as int or string. [...]

And as found in [language.types.intro](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.types.intro.php),  PHP scalar types are  :

> ```
> - boolean
> - integer
> - float (floating-point number, aka double)
> - string
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
public function nullify($force){
  if(is_object($force)) $force = false;
  ...
}
```

Consider it as a temporary solution until you upgrade PHP.